# Which Audioplayer do you recommend to listen Audiobooks?

Tags: software-recommendation, sound

I'm searching for a good Audioplayer in Ubuntu which is able to remember the position it stopped last playing, to resume play even after you closed the application. Which one would you recommend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since version 1.8 Banshee does that:

Look at the [release notes](http://banshee.fm/download/archives/1.8.0/):

> The Audiobooks library is now enabled by default, and audiobook tracks are now better organized into books. The last position in each book is automatically saved, so you can resume playing a book right from where you stopped.

[Get Banshee:](http://packages.ubuntu.com/banshee) [image: Install banshee]

Answer (score 3):

Exaile and Amarok both do resume playback on start.Exaile for GNOME systems,Amarok for KDE systems.

[**exaile** [image: Install exaile]](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/exaile)

[**amarok** [image: Install amarok]](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/amarok)

Comment: is there a special setting needed for exaile? it starts from the track that it stopped, but always just from the beginning, not from the point where it was closed?

Comment: Open Exaile and goto Edit-->Preferences-->Playback and be sure that you have checked **Resume playback on start**. Here is the [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/dlp6f.png).

Comment: hm, the settings here are the same, but for me i always starts at the beginning of the track and not at the specific progress.

Comment: Have you checked the playback time??It works fine for me.Checked both in 10.04 and 10.10.

Comment: yes, it always jumps to the beginning of the certain track after starting the application again.